# Can you have a second "virtual" screen when remoted into your Mac, like you can with Windows RDP?

Tags: remote-desktop, screen-sharing, apple-remote-desktop

I am using 2x monitors on my main workstation (Mac Pro desktop). I can connect to my Macbook via VNC ("sharing") but it only shows the single physical laptop screen and I cannot stretch it across both of my monitors:

[image: MBP via Screen Sharing]

I have Apple Remote Desktop and am connecting from a different Mac, but it's the same - just the single, physical screen. **Is it possible to have a second "virtual" screen when remoted into your Mac, like you can with Windows RDP?** If so, how can I set this up?

Comment: It's possible to spawn separate Login Session (loginwindow process) but it has to be a different user. You can't have two separate sessions for the same user.

Comment: I see, thanks @MateuszSzlosek. That is a bit disappointing, but does make sense, yes.

Comment: I presume you mean 2 'displays' rather than just 2 Spaces?

Comment: That's correct - two physical monitors.

Comment: OK, thanks. Then jksoegaard has your answer below. Wish you luck :)

Comment: Forget about my comment above. I misunderstood the original question. I thought it's about having second (separate) login session with currently logged in user.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, you can - but it requires a bit of third party kit.

**Hardware Solution**

If you add a "[dummy HDMI dongle](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07C4WD9CH)", macOS will think you have an extra display - and that will be accessible when using VNC.

I have linked to a random Amazon vendor of those dongles, but they come in a lot of different models at various price points.

**Software Solution**

A program named [BetterDummy](https://github.com/Brezel31/BetterDummy) can create virtual displays similar to how a dummy HDMI dongle would create a virtual display. That should also work as a display accessible when using VNC. However, I have not actually tried this solution.

Comment: I think you can solve this similar with software - [BetterDummy](https://github.com/Brezel31/BetterDummy) allows to create a second virtual display on the target Mac you want remotely connect to.

Comment: @slartibartfast Thanks for the suggestion - I have included it now!

Comment: I cannot get the resolution to match up between my Mac Mini desktop (1920x1080 - 16:9) and my MBP using either a hardware dongle or the software "BetterDummy" app, but thanks all the same. I do get a second virtual monitor at 16:9, which is nice, but I'm stuck with resolution on the physical laptop screen, which does not match my Desktop monitor.

Answer (score 2):

try pressing option while you switch the radio button in the display settings of the virtual display, it might show "all resolution"  and therefore allow you to select your aspect ratio

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).