# How can I use an iMac 2017 Retina 5k as external monitor for a MacBook Pro M1?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, imac

I want to use an iMac 2017 as an external monitor for a MacBook Pro M1. I know that the iMac is to new for Target Display Mode and is to old to be used for Airplay. Screen sharing is another option, but as the MacBook has limited resolution, I only see a small window on the iMac.

I want to know what are other custom options? I am fine with remote access too, if there is some remote access with less lag, local network, and full resolution.

Comment: Have you looked into [target display mode](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/8042498)?

Comment: 2017 iMac don't support that

Comment: [Astropadsy Luna Display accessory](https://astropad.com/product/lunadisplay/) is able to turn an iPad or Mac into a secondary display for a primary Mac.

Comment: [Here](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/remote-desktop/welcome/mac) you‘ll find Apple’s Remote desktop guide. To reduce any lag you might consider connecting the machines via ethernet cable to your local network (via your router or using a switch). You can easily choose whether to display an observed screen at its actual size or scaled to fit the control/observe window when viewing the computer with the larger screen.

Comment: @slartibartfast this is very useful, only issue is that on 27'' iMac , MacBook Pro 13 inch screen looks very small, even if I try to scale MacBook Pro for max resolution, unlike iMAC I couldn't pull out custom resolution option by pressing option key in display settings. If I try doing scaled on my iMac, it just show thick black border around the shared screen

Comment: please take a look in [this discussion](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/442983/can-you-have-a-second-virtual-screen-when-remoted-into-your-mac-like-you-can) - you can use [BetterDummy](https://github.com/Brezel31/BetterDummy) to create a virtual display with a resolution more fitting to your requirements. That should also work as a display accessible when using VNC.

Comment: great I think this is quite good solution, can you add it as answer so I can accept